# how to import multiple sql file in to same mysql database automatically using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

Sql file to mysql database using shell script. 
I have ten more `.sql` files. But all of the `.sql` files are imported into same database. 
The `.sql` files are in `.gz` format.

Comment: use google. it's not the place where you will find application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bash**:

```
for sql_file in *.sql; do mysql db_name < $sql_file; done
```

(Assuming you wish to import all the sql files in the current directory)